# Factory bodies can't use async

Tags: dart

I'm trying to make a singleton class to read/write my settings

This is what I've tried:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Settings {
  Settings._internal();

  late SharedPreferences prefs;

  factory Settings() async {
    prefs =  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return Settings._internal();
  }

  bool get darkModeEnabled {
    //get prefs
    return false;
  }

  set darkModeEnabled(bool value) {
    // set prefs
  }
}
```

But the compiler gives me the already mentioned error:

> Factory bodies can't use 'async', 'async*', or 'sync*'

So what do you suggest me to do to make SharedPreferences.getInstance() run only once.

Comment: A common solution is to make main async, and initialize it there before calling runApp.